# JQUERY:: $('table > tbody > tr').prepend('td id="'+ i +'"'+  i +'/td');

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/5vss6zLm/3/

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо 'prepend' я мог указать ID определённого TD? Например, указано 'prepend', а мне нужно, чтобы ячейки вставлялись между столбцами "2" и "3", а не только либо в начале, либо в конце.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такой вставки используется [функция before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/), выбираете нужный элемент через селектор и вставляете перед ним:

```
$('table > tbody > tr').find('#2').before('<td id="'+ i +'">'+  i +'</td>');
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/5vss6zLm/5/)

Comment: Прям в точку! Мне это и нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Никита___, если что [after()][1] тоже есть ;)

[1]: http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

```
eq(2)
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: По-моему это не то. Функция 'eq()' равна 'getElementById'.

Comment: @Никита___ откройте документацию, eq выбирает jQuery элемент из набора jQuery по номеру индекса.

Comment: Т.е. с этой функцией вроде должно получится так?) Я не понимаю xD)
http://jsfiddle.net/5vss6zLm/4/

Comment: @Никита___ а какой у вас после eq() метод идет?